# pycharm ssh tunnel to google cloud platform instance was worked and now it does not once I tried to restart the tunnel?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ssh, pycharm

I had a SSH session working on pycharm and then today when I tried to create the tunnel to the google cloud instance I got this error:

Error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) Error while connecting [[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)].
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Anyone know why when I tried to restart the tunnel to the gcp instance that it throws this error?